# Drivers, arm, gpio, pinctrl

Tags: linux, drivers, arm

I have some problems with gpio at banana pi m5. I use Armbian_23.05.0-trunk_Bananapim5_jammy_current_6.1.15.img distribution from official site of Banana Pi.

I need add more UART interfaces at 40 gpios, inititally I have only two UART interfaces at last.

I know about Device Tree. This distribute is using meson-sm1-bananapi-m5.dtb.
Inside of .dtb file I found bus@ff600000, there is bus@34400, and there is pinctrl@40 and there is uart-a/uart-b/uart-c. pinctrl@40 uses compatible meson-g12a-periphs-pinctrl.

uart-a uses groups uart_a_tx\0uart_a_rx

uart-b uses groups uart_b_tx\0uart_b_rx

uart-c uses groups uart_c_tx\0uart_c_rx

Inside bus@ffd00000, serial@24000 uses uart-a and I also seted serial@23000 for uart-b.

I found driver meson-g12a-pinctrl at linux github and saw that uart-c:

```
static const unsigned int uart_c_rx_pins[]      = { GPIOH_6 };
static const unsigned int uart_c_tx_pins[]      = { GPIOH_7 };
```

No GPIOH_6 and 7 at 40 pin board, there are GPIOXs... What can I do? I wanna change GPIOH_6 and 7 for GPIOXs, for example GPIOX_14 and 15 instead of uart_a cts/rts.